# How can I remove certain characters from a string only if it comes before a specific character

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that has parenthesis in it. I want to write a function to remove the parenthesis if they exist and what's inside only if it comes before a comma. Sometimes in my string, there may be more than 1 set of parenthesis in the string; but I would only like to remove the set before the parenthesis.

```
var string1 = "Dog (big), 0"
var string2 = "Dog (medium) (black), 1"
var string3 = "Dog (small) (brown), 1"

What I want:

string1 = "Dog, 0"
string1 = "Dog (medium), 0"
string1 = "Dog (small), 0"
```

Comment: https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use regex:

```
var string2 = "Dog (medium) (black), 1";
    string2 = string2.Replace(string2.Substring(string2.LastIndexOf('(') - 1, string2.LastIndexOf(')') - string2.LastIndexOf('(') + 2), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) to perform this kind of string manipulation. For example:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s\([^\(\)]+\)(?=,)");

var inputs = new[] {
    "Dog (small) (brown), 1",
    "Dog (medium) (black), 1",
    "Dog (big), 0"
};

foreach (var input in inputs)
    Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(input, ""));

// will output:
// Dog (small), 1
// Dog (medium), 1
// Dog, 0
```

This is what the pattern means:

`\s` will match white space, to remove spaces before the bracket.

`\(` will match the opening bracket (the slash escapes because brackets have meaning in regex)

`[^\(\)]+` is a character set - `^` negates, so means anything except an open or close bracket - this is to match the content in a pair of brackets, and avoid matching both pairs of brackets. The `+` is a quantifier meaning one or more times.

`\)` will match the closing bracket

`(?=,)` is a positive look ahead. It says what comes before must be followed by a comma.